# Not able to find "KeyVaultKeyReference"

Tags: .net, azure, .net-core

I am trying to run [this script](https://github.com/AsrOneSdk/published-scripts/blob/master/CopyKeysSinglePass-Az.ps1) in Powershell, but I am encountering the following error when I do so:

```
PS C:\Users\knandan\work\DigitalSolutions\RnD> .\Copy-keys.ps1
At C:\Users\knandan\work\DigitalSolutions\RnD\Copy-keys.ps1:245 char:6
+     [Microsoft.Azure.Management.Compute.Models.KeyVaultSecretReferenc ...
+      ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
Unable to find type [Microsoft.Azure.Management.Compute.Models.KeyVaultSecretReference].
At C:\Users\knandan\work\DigitalSolutions\RnD\Copy-keys.ps1:250 char:6
+     [Microsoft.Azure.Management.Compute.Models.KeyVaultKeyReference]$ ...
+      ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
Unable to find type [Microsoft.Azure.Management.Compute.Models.KeyVaultKeyReference].
    + CategoryInfo          : ParserError: (:) [], ParseException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : TypeNotFound
```

I checked my dotnet version and that is "2.1.507"

```
PS C:\Users\knandan\work\DigitalSolutions\RnD> dotnet --version
2.1.507
```

I also checked the dotnet framework version and its 4.7.2.

[image]

What could be the problem here?

For the background, this is what I am trying to do:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/site-recovery/azure-to-azure-how-to-enable-replication-ade-vms#copy-disk-encryption-keys-to-the-dr-region-by-using-the-powershell-script

Answer (score 0):

do you have the required dll? it is not part of your .net install.

```
dotnet add package Microsoft.Azure.Management.Compute --version 28.3.0
```

Comment: thanks for your response!
But this command wont work, because it expects a project name, and I dont have a project as such. I am just trying to run a powershell script as detailed in the description.

Answer (score 0):

Use the following code to install this package, in which the [Microsoft.Azure.Management.Compute.xml](https://www.powershellgallery.com/packages/AzureRM.Compute/1.2.3/Content/Microsoft.Azure.Management.Compute.xml) initializes a new instance of the `KeyVaultSecretReference`.

```
Install-Module -Name AzureRM.Compute
```

Hope this helps.